# Phonegap File API change, app broken

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I've recently updated a perfectly working android app with the latest version of phonegap.

I've found anything to do with the FILE API has broken completely.
I've started changing my code to amend this, but there is one issue I'm struggling with.

I allow the user to select a image using:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture
```

This used to open up the gallery and return a URL like this:

```
file:///emulated/0/storage/android/test.jpg
```

It now opens (on jelly bean) a new white app "documents" (I think), and returns this:

```
"content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A42014"
```

This breaks everything after it.

**1) How can I go back to getting the old return?**

If I can't, how can I change this new return into a file entry?

Comment: Which cordova version?

Comment: Version:
3.4.0-0.19.7

Answer (score 3):

I spent days on this, so hopefully this can save someone else the pain.
This solution works for VIDEO files only (but the image file fix should be very similar).

Simply run the location return through this function BEFORE using resolveFileSystemURI/resolveFileSystemURL (depending on which version of phonegap you're using).

```
function phoneGapSuperFix(mediaURL){
    //android 4.3 returns
    //content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video%3A38215
    //and we need it to return
    //content://media/external/video/media/38215

    //this checks if it needs fixing, then fixes it or leaves it

   var parts = mediaURL.split("//");
   parts1 =  parts[1].split("/"); 

   if (parts1[0] == "com.android.providers.media.documents"){

   var newMediaURL;
   var endClip = mediaURL.substring(mediaURL.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
   endClip = decodeURIComponent(endClip);
   endClip = endClip.replace(":","/");
   endClip = endClip.split("/");

   newMediaURL = "content://media/external/video/media/" + endClip[1];

       return newMediaURL; 
   } else {
      return mediaURL;
   }
};
```